# PrimeFaces push component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I worked with RichFaces 3.3.3 for a while and it has a component very useful in large operations that take some time: it`s the push component.

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/push.jsf?c=push&tab=usage

Does PrimeFaces has something similar that i can update an object values and not just a String. I saw that you can make this with a String. But I want to pass an object to it.